# Load data into Highcharts with Ajax

Tags: ajax, json, highcharts

I am trying to update high charts on page load and on select menu change with JQUERY AJAX call.  There is data being returned in [[10,1228800000],[10,1228800000]] format.The chart is blank and does not graph any of the data.

Tried several solutions posted on here but none worked.

```
var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {


            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'stats',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'spline'
                },
                title: {text:''},
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                yAxis: {},
                series: []
            };
    var month = 'July';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "month="+month,
        url: "update_visits_chart",
        success: function (data) {

            options.series.push(data);
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        }
    });
```

Any errors?  thanks in advance.
EDIT:

MOST RECENT CODE STILL NOT WORKING:

```
var options = {

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'stats',
                type: 'spline'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {

                type:'datetime',
                tickInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%b %e'
                },
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    align: 'right'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Number of visits'
                },
                min: 0
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e', this.x) +'<br />'+this.y+' visit(s)';
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Number of Visits',
                data: []
            }]
        };
        var month = 'July';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update_visits_chart",
            data: "month="+month,
            success: function(data){
                options.series[0].data = data;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the setData methode of the series object as descriped in documentation. In your case it is `options.series[0].setData(Data)`

And I think you have to turn your Ajax result from string to a real object/array by using `JSON.parse(data)`.

**EDIT:**
@Ricardo Lohmann: in the ajax-call he did not specify the dataType he expects in the response, so jQuery will guess the dataType. But it will not recognize a string starting with `[` as JSON and I doubt his response will be served with correct mime type `application/json`. So specifying the correct mime type should also solve the problem. But I do not have an example of the complete ajax respons of the questioner. So I'm just guessing, too.

I'd recommend the following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "update_visits_chart",
    data: {month: month},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        options.series[0].setData(data);
    }
});
```

@Jugal Thakkar

`$.getJSON` is just a shortcut for the ajax-call above, but it is less flexible because you have less options.

Comment: I didn't think I had to do that.  thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Why he have to do it ? it's not being created dynamically.

Comment: alternatively i think you can use $.getJSON too. Ref http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: I've edited my answer above to answer the questions from the comments.

Comment: This answer is wrong on so many levels. First off you cannot call the method `setData` on the options of highcharts. You have to run it on the highcharts api. Secondly, the call would look like this `$('#container').highcharts(options).chart.Series.setData(data)`. Notice the capital 'S' in Series. Also this doesn't solve the issue in the question. The below answer actually answers it correctly.

Comment: I have a question on [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77239291/6854117) can you please see it?

Answer (score 4):

You have to set directly `data` to series because `data` is already a multidimensional array.
The following code will fix it.
**Change** `options.series.push(data);` **to** `options.series = data;`

Comment: Yes, else you can write the entire chart option creation inside the AJAX callback. eg @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/j4ZYB/

Comment: When I do that I get a blank chart with 479 series items.  I'm assuming those 479 series items in the legend are the actual data points.

Comment: I updated the question code at the bottom, please let me know why this would load a blank chart

Comment: [[1341100800000,10],[1341273600000,10],[1341273600000,10]]

Comment: I have a question on [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77239291/6854117) can you please see it?