# How to retrieve jquery ajax response to php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to pass an jquery ajax response after success into a php variable. this is my code :

process.php

```
    $start = "";
    $end = "";
    if(isset($_POST['tampStart']))
    {
        $start = $_POST['tampStart'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['tampEnd']))
    {
        $end = $_POST['tampEnd'];
    }

    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM `values` WHERE date BETWEEN '".$start."' and '".$end."'";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);

    $prefix = '';
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
        $prefix .= "[\n"."'".$row['month']."'".', '.$row['days']."]".",";
    }

    echo rtrim($prefix, ",");
```

index.php

```
    var dStart = $('#textInput1').val();
var dEnd = $('#textInput2').val();

var form_data = {
    tampStart: dStart,
    tampEnd: dEnd
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    type: 'POST',
    async : true, 
    data: form_data,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(resp){                            
        $('#content').html(resp); 
        //pass to php variable ?
    }
});
```

there is no problem when I put the response into a div ($('#content').append(resp);), but how to put the response into an php variable. Thanks for advance..

update my Highcharts code :

```
function createChart(datan) {
                 //alert(datan);       
                    Highcharts.setOptions({
                        lang: {
                            drillUpText: 'Back to {series.name}'
                        }
                    });

                    var options = {

                        chart: {
                            height: 300
                        },

                        title: {
                            text: 'Highcharts Drilldown Plugin'
                        },

                        xAxis: {
                            categories: true
                        },

                        drilldown: {
                            series: [{
                                id: 'fruits',
                                name: 'Fruits',
                                data: [datan]  //here #*
                            }, {
                                id: 'cars',
                                name: 'Cars',
                                data: [{
                                    name: 'Toyota', 
                                    y: 4,
                                    drilldown: 'toyota'
                                },
                                ['Volkswagen', 3],
                                ['Opel', 5]
                                ]
                            }, {
                                id: 'toyota',
                                name: 'Toyota',
                                data: [
                                    ['RAV4', 3],
                                    ['Corolla', 1],
                                    ['Carina', 4],
                                    ['Land Cruiser', 5]
                                ]
                            }]
                        },

                        legend: {
                            enabled: false
                        },

                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true
                                },
                                shadow: false
                            },
                            pie: {
                                size: '80%'
                            }
                        },

                        series: [{
                            name: 'Overview',
                            colorByPoint: true,
                            data: [{
                                name: 'Fruits',
                                y: 10,
                                drilldown: 'fruits'
                            }, {
                                name: 'Cars',
                                y: 12,
                                drilldown: 'cars'
                            }, {
                                name: 'Countries',
                                y: 8
                            }]
                        }]
                    };

                    // Column chart
                    options.chart.renderTo = 'container1';
                    options.chart.type = 'column';
                    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

                }
```

I make the highcharts config to a function. when I alert(datan), its shown the data from ajax response, but when I put on Drilldown option data (see sign #* above), the highchart config cant read it..

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to do after getting the response.?Whats is the need of saving the response to a php variable.?

Comment: @Deepu The OP want to get the `AJAX` response in `JQuery` and assign into a `PHP` variable

Comment: I want to use that php variable to set data option of Highchart, the result will be ['august', 30], ['september', 30],... etc.
but now I only can put that response into div, cant to php variable..

Comment: Yes, It is impossible, because PHP scripts are running on the server side. `AJAX` is a client side technology - Asynchronous JavaScript And XML

Comment: Why you need php variable for the highchart. Javascript variable will work. just format the reply to meet the requirement of highchart.

Comment: so, how to store the response to a javascript variable, and I hope I can set that variable into highchart data options...

Comment: Very Simple. create a variable and assign the response

Comment: @dev can you so to me, how to do that, I already tried, but the response cant retrieve to javascript variable

Comment: success: function(data){
        options.series[0].setData(data);
    }

Comment: I have var tamp, then on success function I put tamp = resp, but the tamp variable still empty

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223972/load-data-into-highcharts-with-ajax

Comment: @dev how if its an drilldown data series..

Comment: i think it will be easy to give you the right solution if you can put your code block (with the highchart section) online.. like jsfiddle..

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/Vf3yT/

Comment: @CodyDmd, I only can post the code, but not running, because the data of hightchart sould be from the database

Comment: @dev so, how I can set  data: [['Apples', 4],['Pears', 6],    ['Oranges', 2],['Grapes', 8]] dynamically from the database..

Comment: i hope so. Actually if you can emulate your problem in jsfiddle. I am sure there are many including me who can solve it easily for you. You can emulate your ajax responses too on jsfiddle. Just check FAQs

Comment: You can also create highchart in the success function. That will  be most easiest of all.

Comment: check my answer that i changed. May be you get some hint how to do.

Comment: @dev, thanks for update. I recently show you my highcharts config, listed above, please check, whats wrong..

Answer (score 2):

PHP runs on server not on client so the thing you asking is possible only on server. You have to customize this code for your need it gives framework.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    type: 'POST',
    async : true, 
    data: form_data,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(resp){                            
       // $('#content').html(resp); 
        createChart(resp);
    }
});
var chart;
function createChart(data) {
var options = {

    chart: {
        height: 300
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Drilldown Plugin'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: true
    },

    drilldown: {
        series: data}
};


options.chart.renderTo = 'content';
options.chart.type = 'column';
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);



}
```

Comment: I think This is not an answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a client side scripting. You can't assign the javascript value directly to the php variable.

1. One way is to set a SESSION variable in PHP. In your case in process.php file.
2. Another way is to use Database/files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really want to do it this way, you can set a cookie with the desired variable in Javascript and afterwards access it with PHP.

But, there is another way. You can do whatever you want on the client side and when you want to transmit the variable to server-side, just open an ajax connection on the php page which will handle the variable and hand it the actual variable through POST data.