# Sorting data from MySQL and inserting it into a HTML Table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently monitoring 38 individual LED Lighting current and the data is being displayed/imported to a MySQL table. However, that is not what I want to achieve. I want to instead have a concept similar to a table you see in Stock market, where the values(current) are being replaced every other minute or so. Please do advice on how I am suppose achieve the desired outcome. Thank you.

Comment: Use jquery or a similar javascript library and just pole your database and update your view.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use some kind of JS graph library.
You can make a PHP script the get you data from the database, and use ajax to reload your data into a graph.

I'm, suggesting using HighChart.

This is a good example: [Auto Update Highcharts with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560993/auto-update-highcharts-with-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQl Acceding or Descending order and short the values. 
like as

```
SELECT * FROM  `table-name` ORDER BY  `LED` DESC
```