# Auto Update Highcharts with Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I have to update line graph after every 5 seconds. So I am using Highchart  and data should come from the server. Now, being new to Jquery and Ajax I am having trouble how to get value from server to update the chart. I  have gone through a question which is same as that of my problem

I am adding a link for that question.

[Auto Update Highcharts with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560993/auto-update-highcharts-with-ajax)

Please someone can explain me this part-

```
events: {
      load: function() {

    // set up the updating of the chart each second
    var series = this.series[0];
    setInterval(function(){
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    $.getJSON('http://url-to-json-file/index.php', function(jsondata) {
        options.series[0].data = JSON.parse(jsondata.cpu);
    });
    }, 5000);
   }              
}
```

I understand that it is used to update the chart after 5 seconds how is calling I am not understanding.

Please someone help me!

Comment: which front-end technology are you using ?

Comment: @SagarR "front-end technologies" - What did you mean by that? I am using HTML, Javascript if that you want

Comment: ok...instead of using solution of others,try direct demo avail in official site of highchart...here here is link for what you are looking for,http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Comment: I tried this but the real thing I am struggling in is how to get server value by using ajax...I want to know how can I do this

Comment: are you working with php? if yes than your mentioned link is perfect example for you.

Comment: No I am not working with PHP. Only HTML, JQuery

Comment: you wrote that i want to get data from server,so you must be having some code at server-side,otherwise how is it possible to communicate with server?

Comment: I think they are using spring-mvc controller and jsp. I don't know actually as I am doing that part. They just asked me to make a html file and it should refresh after 5 seconds

Comment: ok...no need to worry,ask them to send data in JSON format,once you get data in json than you have almost completed your work...

Comment: that is the problem they will give just a number that I have to take plot it in graph..they will not give JSON

Comment: How will be data received in JS? How will it be send from back-end?

Comment: They are using Spring-Controller and they are displaying data in JSP. Now they want my html so they can now take the value and show it in graph