# HighCharts, Json and Ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax, highcharts

I have a php code that generates me a result in json format

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');  
include_once 'Conexion.php';

$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->conectar();

$fecInicio = (isset($_POST['fechaInicio'])) ? $_POST['fechaInicio'] : '';
$fecFin = (isset($_POST['fechaFin'])) ? $_POST['fechaFin'] : '';

$consulta = "SELECT MONTHNAME(fecha), sum(totalVenta) FROM ventas WHERE fecha BETWEEN '$fecInicio' AND '$fecFin' GROUP BY MONTH(fecha)";

$resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
$resultado->execute();

$result = array();

while ($fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
   array_push($result, array($fila["MONTHNAME(fecha)"], $fila["sum(totalVenta)"])) ;         
}

print json_encode($result);

$conexion=null;
```

With jquery ajax json I get and I want to use in data for a chart with Highcharts. This is the code of my JS

```js
var chart1; 
var options;
$(document).ready(function() { 
   
    var fechaInicio; 
    var fechaFin;

   $("#generarReporte").click(function(){   
            fechaInicio = $("#fechaInicio").val();
            fechaFin = $("#fechaFin").val();

            $.ajax({
              url: "../libreria/ORM/reportes.php",
              type: "POST",
              datatype:"json",    
              data:  {fechaInicio:fechaInicio, fechaFin:fechaFin },    
              success: function(data) {
                 //recibo el json desde PHP y lo paso a string
                  var valores = JSON.stringify(data);
                  console.log(valores); 
                  options.series[0].data = valores;
              }
            });
            $("#opcion5").click();        
        });     
     
   
   $("#opcion5").click(function(){  
    var theModal = $("#modalGraficos").modal({
                            show: false
                            });   
    
    
    options = {    
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container1', 
                    type: "column"               
                },
                title: {
                    text: "Ventas Mensuales"
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: "Período consultado, desde: <strong>"+fechaInicio+"</strong> hasta: <strong>"+fechaFin+"</strong>"
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: "category",
                    labels: {
                        rotation: -45,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: "13px",
                            fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif"
                        }
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: "Pesos AR$"
                    }
                },
                //establecemos los colores de las columnas por Mes
                colors: [
                    "#4572A7", 
                    "rgba(248, 44, 91, 0.61)", 
                    "#89A54E", 
                    "#80699B", 
                    "#3D96AE", 
                    "#DB843D", 
                    "#92A8CD", 
                    "#A47D7C", 
                    "#B5CA92"
                    ],

                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            colorByPoint: true
                        }
                    },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: "Total del Mes: <b>$ {point.y:.2f}</b>"     
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "Ventas por mes",
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        //rotation: -90,
                        rotation: 0,
                        color: "#ffffff",
                        align: "center",
                        format: "{point.y:,.2f}", 
                        y: 30, // 10 pixels down from the top
                        style: {
                            fontSize: "13px",
                            fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif"
                        }
                    },
                    data:[

                    ]
                }]
    }; //fin options

        var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
       
        theModal.on("shown",function(){
           // Recreate the chart now and it will be correct
        }); 
        theModal.modal("show");
    });    

});
```

The result console log is valid json format:
[["March","436400.00"],["April","1302261.50"]]

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soFZj.png)

I can not make the chart. It can help or assist? thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the data you get from ajax call to chart options. this link might help [Load data into Highcharts with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223972/load-data-into-highcharts-with-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

A few clues:

- Chart should mi inititailised in ajax callback
- numbers shoudl not be a strings like you have. It should be  [["March",436400.00],["April",1302261.50]]. To do that set the flag "JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK" in json_encode() function.

Comment: Sebastian Bochan, thank you very much.
It is true. I added: print json_encode ($ result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); and the numerical part has the correct format.

Finally, the return on ajax should be as follows:
success: function (data) {
                   options.series [0] .data = data;
                   chart1 var = new Highcharts.Chart (options);
               }