# How to pass data of multiple arrays in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I want to show the data on charts and i am using dotnet highcharts for it
For now i am able to pass data from controller to the view using JavaScript 
and the data is displaying accordingly but when i insert data or DB is updated i always have to refresh the page, but i want to display data whenever DB is updated on run-time.

I have gone through many searches and i found that using ajax i can be able to perform my certain task

i have found this piece of ajax

```
   $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "update_visits_chart",
data: {month: month},
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
    options.series[0].setData(data);
}
```

here i have a question 
i have multiple arrays with different names as shown bellow

```
var myArrayX_kwh = [];
        var myArrayY_kwh = [];
        var myArrayY_power = [];
        var myArrayY_voltage_1 = [];
        var myArrayY_voltage_2 = [];
        var myArrayY_voltage_3 = [];
        var myArrayY_current_1 = [];
        var myArrayY_current_2 = [];
        var myArrayY_current_3 = [];

        var arry_kwh = [];
        var arry_power = [];
        var arry_voltage_1 = [];
        var arry_voltage_2 = [];
        var arry_voltage_3 = [];
        var arry_current_1 = [];
        var arry_current_2 = [];
        var arry_current_3 = [];


    @foreach (var st in ViewData["Meter_datetime"] as List<double?>)
        {
        @:myArrayX_kwh.push(@st);
    }

    @foreach (var st in ViewData["energy_kwh"] as List<double?>)
    {
        @:myArrayY_kwh.push(@st);
    }
    @foreach (var st in ViewData["power_kw"] as List<double?>)
    {
        @:myArrayY_power.push(@st);
    }
    @foreach (var st in ViewData["voltage_1"] as List<double?>)
    {
        @:myArrayY_voltage_1.push(@st);
    }
    @foreach (var st in ViewData["voltage_2"] as List<double?>)
    {
        @:myArrayY_voltage_2.push(@st);
    }
    @foreach (var st in ViewData["voltage_3"] as List<double?>)
    {
        @:myArrayY_voltage_3.push(@st);
    }
    @foreach (var st in ViewData["current_1"] as List<double?>)
    {
        @:myArrayY_current_1.push(@st);
    }
    @foreach (var st in ViewData["current_2"] as List<double?>)
    {
        @:myArrayY_current_2.push(@st);
    } @foreach (var st in ViewData["current_3"] as List<double?>)
     {
      @:myArrayY_current_3.push(@st);
    }


    for (var i = 0; i < myArrayX_kwh.length; i++) {
        arry_kwh.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_kwh[i], });
        arry_power.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_power[i], });
        arry_voltage_1.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_voltage_1[i], });
        arry_voltage_2.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_voltage_2[i], });
        arry_voltage_3.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_voltage_3[i], });
        arry_current_1.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_current_1[i], });
        arry_current_2.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_current_2[i], });
        arry_current_3.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_current_3[i], });
    }
```

how to pass them in ajax data field ? 
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
    var myArrayX_kwh = [];
    var myArrayY_kwh = [];
    var myArrayY_power = [];
    var myArrayY_voltage_1 = [];
    var myArrayY_voltage_2 = [];
    var myArrayY_voltage_3 = [];
    var myArrayY_current_1 = [];
    var myArrayY_current_2 = [];
    var myArrayY_current_3 = [];

    var arry_kwh = [];
    var arry_power = [];
    var arry_voltage_1 = [];
    var arry_voltage_2 = [];
    var arry_voltage_3 = [];
    var arry_current_1 = [];
    var arry_current_2 = [];
    var arry_current_3 = [];


@foreach (var st in ViewData["Meter_datetime"] as List<double?>)
    {
    @:myArrayX_kwh.push(@st);
}

@foreach (var st in ViewData["energy_kwh"] as List<double?>)
{
    @:myArrayY_kwh.push(@st);
}
@foreach (var st in ViewData["power_kw"] as List<double?>)
{
    @:myArrayY_power.push(@st);
}
@foreach (var st in ViewData["voltage_1"] as List<double?>)
{
    @:myArrayY_voltage_1.push(@st);
}
@foreach (var st in ViewData["voltage_2"] as List<double?>)
{
    @:myArrayY_voltage_2.push(@st);
}
@foreach (var st in ViewData["voltage_3"] as List<double?>)
{
    @:myArrayY_voltage_3.push(@st);
}
@foreach (var st in ViewData["current_1"] as List<double?>)
{
    @:myArrayY_current_1.push(@st);
}
@foreach (var st in ViewData["current_2"] as List<double?>)
{
    @:myArrayY_current_2.push(@st);
} @foreach (var st in ViewData["current_3"] as List<double?>)
 {
  @:myArrayY_current_3.push(@st);
}


for (var i = 0; i < myArrayX_kwh.length; i++) {
    arry_kwh.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_kwh[i], });
    arry_power.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_power[i], });
    arry_voltage_1.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_voltage_1[i], });
    arry_voltage_2.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_voltage_2[i], });
    arry_voltage_3.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_voltage_3[i], });
    arry_current_1.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_current_1[i], });
    arry_current_2.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_current_2[i], });
    arry_current_3.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_current_3[i], });
}
```

}

For updating charts after some interval you can use following code :

```
var interval = window.setInterval(ajaxMethodCall, 20000);
```

above code will make ajax call after every 20 secs.

Using Polling :

```
$(document).ready(function poll() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : "/Test/TestServlet",
                type : "GET",
                //dataType : "json",
                //data : dataArray,

                success : function(data) {
                    alert("success")
                    dt.setValue(data.value);
            var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container2',
                zoomType: 'xy',
                resetZoomButton: {
                    position: {
                        align: 'right', // by default
                        verticalAlign: 'top', // by default
                        x: -250,
                        y: 5,
                        //height: 25
                    },

                    relativeTo: 'chart'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Power vs Date & Time',
                style: {
                    //color: '#FF00FF',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                // categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Power (KW)'
                }

            },
            plotOptions: {  
                series: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 3
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                    name : 'Power kW',
                    data: arry_power,
            }],

        });

                },
                error : function(data) {
                    console.log("error polling");
                },
                complete : poll,
            })
        }, 5000);
    });
```

here it is for one chart

```
 var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container2',
                zoomType: 'xy',
                resetZoomButton: {
                    position: {
                        align: 'right', // by default
                        verticalAlign: 'top', // by default
                        x: -250,
                        y: 5,
                        //height: 25
                    },

                    relativeTo: 'chart'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Power vs Date & Time',
                style: {
                    //color: '#FF00FF',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                // categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Power (KW)'
                }

            },
            plotOptions: {  
                series: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 3
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                    name : 'Power kW',
                    data: arry_power,
            }],

        });
```

Comment: i have tried your method and i have done this 

 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Home/MultiGraph",
                data: dataArray,
                dataType: 'json',
                sussces: function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        options.series[i].setData(data);
                    }

                }

            });

but still unable to get any thing i still have to refresh my page to view updated data
i have 4 charts in my view so i added a loop in which i have passed my data having dataArray

Comment: If you want to make update call after some interval you can refer new edited code. Which is very simple. Just replace ajaxMethodCall with respective ajax call

Comment: what about polling ? 
i am using this 
(function poll() {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                            $.ajax({
                            url: "/Home/MultiGraph",
                            type: "GET",
                            success: function (dataArray) {
                                console.log("polling");
                            },
                            dataType: "json",
                            complete: poll,
                        })
                    }, 5000);
                });

Comment: Why don't you try above mentioned code for now and let me know. I will get back to you on poll.

Comment: tried but nothing happens i might be missing something

Comment: Try the new code and let me know if it's working or not. I tried from my side, It's working perfectly for me

Comment: What is you error?? Error Description? Can you explain what you want to do? Are you able to make ajax call

Comment: no error is shown
 also i have tried this 
$.getJSON(url, data, success);
following this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223972/load-data-into-highcharts-with-ajax
but no use

Comment: Explain me what you want? I will try to give you some basic code template

Comment: all i want is whenever the database is updated the data on the charts will be shown automatically (if i am on the charts view ). till now i am able to view updated data when i refresh the page but i want it show automatically

Comment: Then use polling method with ajax mentioned above. you can check your browser console for every call output. You can also print on server console some data to check if you are able to call MultiGraph page properly

Comment: The ajax code written by you can you give it to me. I will convert it into polling

Comment: ok here it is i have followed the following example with slight modifications 
https://gist.github.com/jasdeepkhalsa/4353139/1aa5ad9ed61ba22c3e8f8dfc42eea2bd73bd66f8#file-recursivepolling-js

Comment: (function poll() {
 
                setTimeout(function () {
                   
                    $.ajax({                      
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Home/MultiGraph/",
                        //dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            alert("success")
                           dt.setValue(data.value);                       
                        }, 
                    });
                    poll();
                }, 5000);
            })();

Comment: by commenting dataType i am able to see success message
i have changed the name of dataArray to dt

Comment: I have changed AJAX call according to your use for polling just replace your code with this. I will work

Comment: but from where the data is coming from then ?

Comment: data of success method will contain response from server

Comment: it only shows success message for one time only 
after that when i update my DB nothing happens :(

Comment: It will show success message for every 5 sec. After every 5 sec, a call to your URL made by poll/ajax. You can write something on your server console to check the call made by ajax/poll. Data will refresh every 5 sec.

Comment: On which browser console your checking the output

Comment: chrome 
the ajax code which i provided you is showing me success message every 5 seconds

Comment: Well that's the output for ajax/poll call. Do you need anything else?

Comment: yes butt it's not showing me the updated data it's just showing me the success message

Comment: the chart is still updating when i refresh the page i want it to show updated data without refreshing

Comment: Where is your HighChart related code.Call that code using polling and ajax. Give me your highchart related code

Comment: in controller i have set all the data in viewdata and passed them into the view then i have initialized the charts in view and i am using 4 different charts in one view and they all should be updated automatically without refreshing the page

Comment: You have to call  initialization of view using poll

Comment: You can add this code in success function of your ajax call. It will create your chart for every 5 secs

Comment: not possible as it will remove the chart from the view

Comment: declare chart2 outside ajax call and initialize it in ajax success method

Comment: all the chart initialization is out side the ajax/poll call

Comment: just call chart initialization function in ajax

Comment: Have you got the output?

Comment: i have tried but the code is not running as it disappears the charts from the view

Comment: there is no success message and it just show me empty view without charts

Comment: Let me know when you post new question with updated code. Add code related to chart and ajax call

Comment: As I'm going offline for now. I will answer you question tomorrow.And dont forget to post your new question here.

Comment: I have posted a new question with details please goto this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285852/unable-to-pass-json-data-into-ajax-success-call-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need real-time data updates then I would suggest a [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) library. As stated on the official page:

> SignalR allows bi-directional communication between server and client.
>   Servers can now push content to connected clients instantly as it
>   becomes available

You will simply wait for database change notification and push the updated data back to client and update the highcharts.

[Tutorial #1](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Broadcast-Real-time-SQL-69dd9fcc)

[Tutorial #2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874240/SignalR-Database-update-notifications-in-ASP-NET-M)