# How to display the ajax response

Tags: php, ajax

I've created a chart and I want to update in real time, that's why I use ajax. My question is, how to display the ajax response? Below is my sample script of my chart. Please help me. Thank you very well.

Chart.php -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: "TITLE"
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Present',
            data: [*//must display the ajax response here//*]
        }]
    });
});
```

ajax.php

```
<script>
function fanc_no(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        success: function(result){
            $("#container").html(result);
        }
    });
}  
window.setInterval(function(){
  func_no();
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load data into Highcharts with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223972/load-data-into-highcharts-with-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `load` function:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function () {

            // set up the updating of the chart each second
            var series = this.series[0];
            setInterval(function () {
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                    y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, inside the `setInterval` function, you have to call your ajax and pass the result as shown.

Take a look at [the official docs](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update) for it.

Comment: Hello! is there any other option for bar graph? this is shown for line graph.

Comment: I guess this works for both line and bar graphs. If not try answer below.

Comment: It's not working. It always say, this page is slowing down the website.

Comment: I am using bar with negative stack of highcharts and i want to update in 5 seconds.

Comment: You have to tell what exactly is not working, what tells you that the page is slowing down the website? Maybe your amount of data is to high?